# How do you link Sparkle.framework to a Qt application?

Tags: macos, frameworks, qt5, qt-creator

I've built Sparkle.framework and added the following to my .pro file:

```
mac: LIBS += -F$$PWD/../../../opensource/sparkle/ -framework Sparkle

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../opensource/sparkle
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../opensource/sparkle
```

My program builds and links. However, when I debug or run I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Sparkle
  Referenced from: /Users/foo/build-foo-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_clang_64bit-Debug/foo/applications/foo/Foo.app/Contents/MacOS/Foo
  Reason: image not found
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently had issues with Sparkle integration in Qt.

So after this I decided to write a quick walk-through for getting the client side of the framework up and running. You can find my post at: http://www.discoversdk.com/knowledge-base/using-sparkle-in-qt

you may want to add the Sparkle.framework to the system root /Library

Sometimes the dependency problems can be solved by running:
~/Qt5.5.1/5.5/clang_64/bin/macdeployqt [path to the bundle]

this will invoke the **otool** application that adds dependencies to your application bundle